# apex5.1, how to set custom login page

Tags: oracle-apex, oracle-apex-5.1

I need to set a custom page login in apex5.0
If login is invalid, the standard error msg should be displayed.

However, i have a table that contains an expiry date for the user. I want to add a check user is expired then he should not login the system and message 'No access' displayed.  if sys_date > expiry_date.
How is it possible to do that?

Answer (score 1):

The best way to do this is to create your own authentication scheme.

Create your own function which checks if username and password match with your user table, and then check if expiry_date > sysdate.  Add a new authentication scheme (shared components -> authentication schemes -> create and select custom as the scheme type.  Then add your function in there.

Comment: is there a way to do it via validation as well ??

Comment: You could try just creating a validation on login page (typically P101) of type rows returned.  Something like `SELECT 1 FROM <table that contains expiry date> WHERE UPPER(username) = UPPER(:P101_USERNAME) AND sysdate > expiry_date` then set error message to whatever you want (I would suggest something a little more helpful, like account expired).

Comment: hi, i have an online workspace .. can u pls check why its not working..  
 https://apex.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=4000:1:33161643494761::NO:RP:FB_FLOW_ID,F4000_P1_FLOW:92049,92049
 
 Workspace: AKIKA   ,  AKIKA1508@GMAIL.COM / TESTING123
 Application 92049 - Akika1508 1
 
 Table: tbl_user 
 if apex_user Name = login_name in table tbl_user
 and sysdate > end_date  tbl_user and status = 'Y' 
 then error msg is to be displayed.. no access

Comment: You need to make a custom login function to achieve what you want.  There is no expiry date on managed apex users so you can't do that check.  At present you are not referencing your users table at all, you can only login as a user which you have set up on apex.  If you follow the instructions on my initial post then you will be able to add your expiry date check.

Apologies for my suggestion in last comment, having thought about this more I realise that would not work.

Comment: I've implemented it for you.  I created a custom login which calls a package (akika_sec) which checks your username and password and end_date.  I then made a validation to capture this on the front end and display your error message.  You can test it by logging in as AKIKA@TEST.COM (success), and TEST@MY.COM (failure due to end date).  

To implement this in a real app you should hash your password on the way in to the database and then check against that in your login function (easy update with the function I created).

Comment: thanks a lot :)  for ldap auth, which function should be used.? is there an in-built function or criteria to check?

Comment: There is an ldap option (`shared components -> authentication schemes -> create -> scheme type`) when creating a new authentication scheme which you can try.  For more complicated ldap auth you would need to make your own function.